# When Irun this nothing happens. Am I missing something?

Tags: python, python-3.3

```
def numbers(num1,num2):
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter another number: "))
    return num1,num2

def display():
    print("The numbers that you chose are",num1,"and",num2)

def count():
    for x in range(1,11):
        print (x)
```

Comment: I will work better if you call any of these function from the [`__main__` conditional](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html)

Comment: Most concise title ever...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function.

```
def numbers(num1,num2):
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter another number: "))
    return num1,num2

def display():
    print("The numbers that you chose are",num1,"and",num2)

def count():
    for x in range(1,11):
        print (x)

count()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your end result is supposed to be, exactly, but the reason this doesn't work is that you never do anything with it.

Remember that function declaration (like class declaration) is just building a tool to do Work. In order to USE that tool, you have to CALL the function (or instantiate the class).

```
def numbers(num1,num2): # You're not actually giving this anything, so why
                        # are there parameters here?
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter another number: "))
    return num1,num2
# numbers is now a tool in your toolkit. Think of it like a hammer. Just because you
# went and made yourself a hammer doesn't mean your nail is pounded in!

def display():
    print("The numbers that you chose are",num1,"and",num2)
# likewise, display is now a saw. Just because you bought a saw from Home Depot doesn't
# mean your board is cut in two.    

def count():
    for x in range(1,11):
        print (x)
# I'm out of tool analogies, so....
```

Now to actually USE these, you need to call them. If you want to run the whole thing 10 times (I'm assuming?) then you can do:

```
def numbers(): # I removed those parameters
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter another number: "))
    return num1, num2

def display():
    num1, num2 = numbers() # CALL numbers
    print("The numbers that you chose are",num1,"and",num2)

def count():
    for _ in range(10):
        display() # CALL display

count() # CALL count
```

Answer (score 0):

U Just Need to Call The Function . Functions Just Dont Call Themselves By Themselves  ;)

use

```
numbers()
display()
count()
```

Order Them Depending on Wich one u Want to Call First 
or u Can Call a function from a Function By Simply Adding "NameofFuction()" without Quotes 
into some other function
Hope This Helps :))